# how smooth refinished hardwood floor is supposed to be?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

How smooth should be the refinished (3 finish layers) hardwood floor surface? Is this normal?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floor looks good *and* the finish is not fully filling the wood grain. This wood has a pretty deep grain - oak I assume.
This is more eo be expected from a water borne floor finish. Waterborne finishes are a more "natural" look  compared to the old school polyurethane finish- which is still very widely used.

We often will pay the finishers to do an extra coating when we have floors done and it does help but it is all just preference.

Comment: Super happy to hear this is normal and the floor looks good. At least some reassurance that my thousands were not completely wasted :) Thank you!